# Script fails with AttributeError when run in CMD, but executes fine in IDLE

Tags: python, cmd, python-idle

I am quite new and confused. I tried a simple script with tkinter and it worked fine in IDLE but when i try to launch it from CMD - the tkinter window opens and it looks fine , but when you attempt to click any button or file menu options an AttributeError raises:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1489, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "060214_Manual_Evaluation_of_Protein-protein_Cross-Links.py", line 13, in Open_csv
  self.CsvPath = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'filedialog'
```

I am thankful for any input or where i could possibly find more information about differences between IDLE and CMD.

Comment: Check the version of python you are using... Cmd seems to be using Py2 and IDLE Py3. Check version first.

Comment: Thank you for answering! The version is the same, i have checked.

Comment: After giving the answer below, I decided that it was a bug for IDLE to mask bugs that will become visible as soon as one runs the code directly in Python.  The fix will be in 3.5.3 and is already in current 3.6.0 releases.  With the fix, `import tkinter; tkinter.filedialog` fails when run in IDLE, just as when run in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People asked about python version because tk.filedialog is spelled differently in 2.x.  However, I suspect that your problem is that Idle runs code in a managed environment that masks a bug in your unposted code of not properly importing tkinter.filedialog.  To illustrate, the follow is from the standard 3.4.2 console interpreter

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> tk.filedialog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'filedialog'
```

Here are the same statements in Idle's Shell.

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> tk.filedialog
<module 'tkinter.filedialog' from 'C:\\Programs\\Python34\\lib\\tkinter\\filedialog.py'>
```

The reason that there is no error is because Idle has already imported the filedialog submodule as `tkinter.filedialog` (in sys.modules).  If this is your problem also, a solution for you is to add the import below and refer to 'filedialog' without the 'tk' prefix.

```
>>> from tkinter import filedialog
>>> filedialog
<module 'tkinter.filedialog' from 'C:\\Programs\\Python34\\lib\\tkinter\\filedia
log.py'>
>>> filedialog.askopenfilename
<function askopenfilename at 0x0000000000498BF8>
```

If this does not solve this issue, edit your question to add a truly minimal code example and explain exactly how you run both with Idle and 'CMD' (is this cmd.exe on Windows, or what?).

Comment: Thanks very much, it works when i import the submodules separately. i did not know that was the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like *IDLE* sets a different PYTHONPATH, or uses a different python executable; make sure you use the same version of python by checking `sys.version_info` from both and comparing `sys.path`.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I did that and the only difference is that from idle i get an extra path - 'C:\\Python33\\Lib\\idlelib'.

Comment: well, does that path contain anything interesting? both pythons are python3.3, according to `sys.version_info`?

Comment: i am browsing through it now , but can't really tell what is interesting as i barely understand how python works. Yes the versions are absolutely the same.