# pandas has no attribute read_html raspberry pi

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, raspberry-pi

```
import pandas as pd

f_states = pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
```

So above script works fine when calling it directly in the python shell:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> f_states = pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
```

But does not work while doing `python script.py` with the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_html'`.

This is the same script but called in two different ways, so why does one work but the other not?

Comment: Is is the same python version that you're using when running a script? Try `which python` in the shell and compare to `import sys; print(sys.version);` in your console.

Comment: yes, both returns 2.7.9 default for `rasbian`

Comment: This seems to be a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372092/script-fails-with-attributeerror-when-run-in-cmd-but-executes-fine-in-idle

Comment: Do you by any chance have a python script named `pandas.py` in the same directory? Perhaps you're importing that script instead of the `pandas` module. You can check by adding `print(pd.__file__)` to your `script.py` file right after importing `pandas.

Answer (score -2):

You need to update pandas, use:

```
pip install pandas==1.3
```